# How to display the column names that contain the same cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table where the columns have the same value. Is there a function where I can search for a value in the cell and display the column names that contain it? For example, When I search for "The Matrix", I want to display HBO Max and Netflix since The Matrix is present in both columns.  I tried INDEX+MATCH but I can't seem to show what I want to. Thanks in advance!

[image]

`=INDEX(A2:D14,MATCH(A1:D1,A2:D14))` - resulted in #N/A

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no duplicates in single column itself or you need column header to be returned once even if there are this might work:

```
=FILTER(A1:D1,BYCOL(A2:D6,LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(x=G2))))>0,"Not found")
```

[image]